# JavaScript taking extra time between calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

```
console.log("FADIG");
console.log(modal);
modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
console.log("background GONE!");
modal.animate({
    "opacity": 0
}, 300, function () {
    console.log("FADED OUT MODAL");
    modal.css({
        'opacity': 1,
        'visibility': 'hidden',
        'top': topMeasure
    });
    unlockModal();
});
```

That's my JavaScript code. I know that it finds the object named `modal` just fine. It then immediately spits out `background GONE!` then it takes about 10 seconds for me to see `FADED OUT MODAL`. Which means the animate didn't run for a good 10 seconds.

Any idea why this would be?

Comment: What are `modal` and `modalBG` and are any other animations called on them elsewhere?

Comment: And can you confirm--are `modal` and `modalBG` jQuery objects?

Comment: are `modal` and `modalBG` the same element?

Comment: Should I assume that `options.animationSpeed` _isn't_ five seconds?

Comment: `modal` and `modalBG` are different jQuery objects. They are both confirmed jQuery objects. `options.animationSpeed` is more like 300ms.

Comment: You should provide more info about the variables you are using in your code above if you expect to receive a good answer.

Comment: then I see no reason for it to take ten seconds. It should be `300ms` if they are different objects, and `300ms + 2*animationSpeed` if they are the same object.

Comment: No typo. `options.animationspeed` is, in fact, 300. Also, `modal != modalBG`

Comment: Note that `background GONE` logs before the background starts disappearing.

Comment: Why didn't you provide your `options` object here? This is an unnecessary back-and-forth with several people trying to figure out what exactly your code is doing.

Comment: Could this be recreated in jsFiddle?

Comment: I'm afraid the problem _isn't_ in the code you posted.

Comment: have you tried fadeOut(options.animationspeed, function(){ /* second anim here */ }); ? if one of the object is in the other it may interfer as fadeout set display none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super simple... I think a few animations were being queued, so I changed it to:

`modal.stop().animate` and all is well

Comment: This is a close reason more than an answer.